# Elements created with JS are not going on to a new line

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have been doing a to do list for my first project. I have made a button that creates a new div with the users input. When I click the DIV I expect to start on a new line but it gets stuck on the same line. Anyone know what I have done wrong? sorry for the css code, I am messing about with it and trying to learn.  Thanks

```js
const toDoContainer = document.createElement('P');
let btnAdd = document.getElementById('btnAdd');
let toDoContent = document.createTextNode(toDoItem);

console.log(toDoItem);


btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let toDoItem = document.getElementById('toDoItem').value;
    alert(toDoItem);

    const toDiv = document.createElement('div');
    toDiv.classList = "toDiv";


    document.querySelector('.itemsContainer').appendChild(toDiv);

    const toDoContainer = document.createElement('li');


    let toDoContent = document.createTextNode(toDoItem);
    toDoContainer.appendChild(toDoContent);

    toDiv.appendChild(toDoContainer);



    toDoContainer.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
        toDoContainer.removeChild(toDoContent);
    })

    toDoContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
        toDoContainer.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
        toDoContainer.style.color = "#C0C0C0"

    })

});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #c80808
}

#header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 25em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 3px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
}

.main {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:
}

#toDoItem {
    height: 2em;
    width: 23em;
    padding: 10px;
    /* margin: 10px 30px; */
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 9px darkred;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#btnAdd {
    background-color: rgb(160, 0, 252);
    width: 4em;
    height: 3.75em;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0.90;
    /* margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 50px; */
    color: white;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bolder;
    box-shadow: 5px 8px 9px darkred;
}

.itemsContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.toDiv {
    min-width: 30%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    min-width: 45vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: white;
    min-height: 2vh;
    min-width: 30%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="title">To Do List</h1>
        <BR>
        <p class="subtext">This is a project I have worked on from scratch. It was developed with the intent to improve my programming skills.</p>  
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <input id='toDoItem' type="text" placeholder="Todo's"/> 
        <button id="btnAdd">+</button>
        
    </div>

    <div class="itemsContainer">
    <!-- <div class="toDoList"> -->
    

    
    </div>
</div>    
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>`. It's only allowed in `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: DevEd on youtube contained it in a div. Would need to make a ul as well then?

Comment: I would trust the [<li> documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) over some unknown hacker on youtube. I forgot it is also valid in a `<menu>`

Comment: See [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `flex-direction: column` to the css for your itemsContainer class should put them in a vertical list

```
.itemsContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped I was trying for hours haha!

Comment: No problem! The default flex-direction is 'row' so without specifying 'column' the child elements will just sit side-by-side.

Comment: @Ryjonzy if this answer helped you please be sure to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it to help any future viewers